# Detect iPhone fall while the app runs in background

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

Can I detect iPhone fall using accelerometer while the app runs in background?

Comment: An answer to one of your previous questions already mentions the fact that you can't run code while your app is in the background except in a few cases.

Comment: The allowed cases of background apps are: VoIP, GPS, music.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can detect a fall when in foreground—but in background you are not running. So, no, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good feature to have your phone ringing if it fall!
However I'm pretty sure you cannot run such code in background unfortunately.